CaptureRequest and ImageReader Frame Rate Issue: Only 15 FPS Despite Setting 60 FPS
I am developing an Android application that captures images from the camera at 30 FPS using the Camera2 API. I have set up my CaptureRequest and ImageReader to achieve this, but I only receive about 15 images per second in the onImageAvailable callback. Even after lowering the resolution and increasing the frame rate, the result remains the same.
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest;
import android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult;
import android.hardware.camera2.params.StreamConfigurationMap;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Range;
import android.util.Size;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraSocket";
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;

    private Button capture_start_button;
    private Button capture_stop_button;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession;
    private ImageReader imageReader;

    private Range<Integer> TARGET_FPS_RANGE;
    private int TARGET_WIDTH = 176;
    private int TARGET_HEIGHT = 144;
    private boolean isCapturing = false;

    private Handler captureHandler;
    private Runnable captureRunnable;

    private int process_index = 0;
    private int capture_index = 0;

    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener surfaceTextureListener = new SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
            openCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(@NonNull SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        }
    };

    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice = camera;
            setCameraCharacter();
            startCameraPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };

    private void setCameraCharacter(){
        try {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Range<Integer>[] fpsRanges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
            if (fpsRanges != null) {
                for (Range<Integer> range : fpsRanges) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Supported FPS Range: " + range);
                }
                TARGET_FPS_RANGE = fpsRanges[fpsRanges.length-1];
                Log.d(TAG, "set TARGET_FPS_RANGE to " + TARGET_FPS_RANGE);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No FPS Ranges available.");
            }

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            Size[] outputSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
            if(outputSizes != null){
                for(Size s: outputSizes){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Supported scale: " + s);
                }
                TARGET_WIDTH = outputSizes[outputSizes.length-1].getWidth();
                TARGET_HEIGHT = outputSizes[outputSizes.length-1].getHeight();
                Log.d(TAG, "set scale to " + TARGET_WIDTH + "*" + TARGET_HEIGHT);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No scale available.");
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        capture_start_button = findViewById(R.id.record_start_button);
        capture_stop_button = findViewById(R.id.record_stop_button);
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView);

        capture_start_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startCapturing();
            }
        });

        capture_stop_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopCapturing();
            }
        });

        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(surfaceTextureListener);
        captureHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    }

    private CaptureRequest.Builder createCaptureRequest(int kind) throws CameraAccessException {
        CaptureRequest.Builder builder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(kind);
        if(TARGET_FPS_RANGE != null){
            builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, TARGET_FPS_RANGE);
        }
        return builder;
    }

    private void startCapturing() {
        if (cameraDevice == null || isCapturing) {
            return;
        }
        if (!hasCameraPermission()) {
            requestCameraPermission();
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "startCapturing");
        try {
            setUpImageReader();
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT);
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            Surface imageReaderSurface = imageReader.getSurface();

            CaptureRequest.Builder builder = createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            builder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            builder.addTarget(imageReaderSurface);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, imageReaderSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                    isCapturing = true;
                    startCapturingImages();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Capturing started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void stopCapturing() {
        if (cameraDevice == null || !isCapturing) {
            return;
        }
        isCapturing = false;
        if (captureRunnable != null) {
            captureHandler.removeCallbacks(captureRunnable);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Capturing stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void setUpImageReader() {
        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.JPEG, 50);
        File curDir = getFilesDir();

        File folder = FileManager.makeDirIfNotExists(curDir, "myCameraDir");
        if(folder == null) return;
        String folderPath = folder.getPath();
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                if (!isCapturing) return;
                Image image;
                while((image = reader.acquireNextImage()) != null){
                    process_increment();
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }

    private void process_increment(){
        process_index += 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "process: " + process_index);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            if (!hasCameraPermission()) {
                requestCameraPermission();
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private boolean hasCameraPermission() {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void requestCameraPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startCameraPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        if (surfaceTexture == null) return;
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT);
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            captureRequestBuilder = createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    cameraCaptureSession = session;
                    updatePreview();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void updatePreview() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) return;
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startCapturingImages() {
        captureRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isCapturing) {
                    captureStillPicture();
                    capture_index += 1;
//                    Log.d(TAG, "capture: " + capture_index);
                    captureHandler.postDelayed(this, 20);
                }
            }
        };
        captureHandler.post(captureRunnable);
    }

    private void captureStillPicture() {
        if (cameraDevice == null) return;

        try {
            CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(imageReader.getSurface());

            Range<Integer> currentFpsRange = captureBuilder.get(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE);
            cameraCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (cameraDevice != null) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        if (imageReader != null) {
            imageReader.close();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}


In this case, I got the result below:
2024-07-23 12:14:40.744 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  startCapturing
2024-07-23 12:14:41.353 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 1
2024-07-23 12:14:41.416 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 2
2024-07-23 12:14:41.477 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 3
2024-07-23 12:14:41.537 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 4
2024-07-23 12:14:41.601 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 5
2024-07-23 12:14:41.669 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 6
2024-07-23 12:14:41.731 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 7
2024-07-23 12:14:41.797 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 8
2024-07-23 12:14:41.858 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 9
2024-07-23 12:14:41.920 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 10
2024-07-23 12:14:41.974 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 11
2024-07-23 12:14:42.037 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 12
2024-07-23 12:14:42.100 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 13
2024-07-23 12:14:42.164 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 14
2024-07-23 12:14:42.227 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 15
2024-07-23 12:14:42.288 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 16
2024-07-23 12:14:42.356 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 17
2024-07-23 12:14:42.425 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 18
2024-07-23 12:14:42.486 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 19
2024-07-23 12:14:42.548 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 20
2024-07-23 12:14:42.609 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 21
2024-07-23 12:14:42.675 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 22
2024-07-23 12:14:42.744 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 23
2024-07-23 12:14:42.805 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 24
2024-07-23 12:14:42.861 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 25
2024-07-23 12:14:42.929 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 26
2024-07-23 12:14:42.994 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 27
2024-07-23 12:14:43.057 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 28
2024-07-23 12:14:43.114 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 29
2024-07-23 12:14:43.176 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  process: 30

Here are my efforts to adjust the frame rate of the CaptureRequest.Builder and the resolution of the ImageReader.
private void setCameraCharacter(){
        try {
            CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(CAMERA_SERVICE);
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
            Range<Integer>[] fpsRanges = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);
            if (fpsRanges != null) {
                for (Range<Integer> range : fpsRanges) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Supported FPS Range: " + range);
                }
                TARGET_FPS_RANGE = fpsRanges[fpsRanges.length-1];
                Log.d(TAG, "set TARGET_FPS_RANGE to " + TARGET_FPS_RANGE);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No FPS Ranges available.");
            }

            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            Size[] outputSizes = map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);
            if(outputSizes != null){
                for(Size s: outputSizes){
                    Log.d(TAG, "Supported scale: " + s);
                }
                TARGET_WIDTH = outputSizes[outputSizes.length-1].getWidth();
                TARGET_HEIGHT = outputSizes[outputSizes.length-1].getHeight();
                Log.d(TAG, "set scale to " + TARGET_WIDTH + "*" + TARGET_HEIGHT);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No scale available.");
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

2024-07-23 12:14:25.710 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [12, 15]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.710 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [15, 15]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.710 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [14, 20]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.711 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [20, 20]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.711 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [24, 24]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.711 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [14, 25]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.712 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [25, 25]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.712 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [14, 30]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.712 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [30, 30]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.713 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [15, 60]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.713 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [30, 60]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.713 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported FPS Range: [60, 60]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.713 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  set TARGET_FPS_RANGE to [60, 60]
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 4096x3072
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 4096x2304
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 4096x1864
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3648x2056
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3648x1680
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3648x2056
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3072x3072
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3840x2160
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3840x1760
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3840x1648
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3120x2340
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 2560x1080
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3280x2448
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3264x2448
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3264x1840
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 3008x2256
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 2448x2448
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 2368x1080
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 2048x1536
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1920x1080
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1584x720
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1440x1080
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1456x1456
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1664x768
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1440x720
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1280x960
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1280x720
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 1088x1080
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 960x720
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 960x540
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 720x720
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 720x540
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 640x480
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 640x360
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 736x412
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 544x408
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 480x360
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 400x400
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 352x288
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 320x240
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 208x144
2024-07-23 12:14:25.717 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  Supported scale: 176x144
2024-07-23 12:14:25.718 12416-12416 CameraSocket            com.example.myapplication            D  set scale to 176*144


Here: imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(TARGET_WIDTH, TARGET_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.JPEG, 50);. Replace ImageFormat.JPEG with ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 works well.

As you've noticed, it works fine with YUV_420_888.  JPEG encoding is not guaranteed to be particularly fast, so the documentation explicitly says that JPEG outputs have extra stall duration, so if you request JPEG for every frame, you will probably run slower than your requested target FPS.
So stick to YUV_420_888 if you need something to process for every frame, and leave JPEG for snapshots where you just want to save a JPEG to disk.
